# How to link array of records in a text file to a grid of buttons in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to link records within a text file to a grid of buttons so that when you click on a button it displays information from a specific line within the text file.

[EDIT] here is the code

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button And ctrl.BackColor = Color.Gold Then
            btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Gold_Click
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Button And ctrl.BackColor = Color.Silver Then
            btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Silver_CLick
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Button And ctrl.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange Then
            btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Bronze_CLick
        End If

    Next

    Using sr As New IO.StreamReader("seatingplan.txt")
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            arr = sr.ReadLine.Split(vbTab)
            SeatArray(x, 0) = arr(0)
            SeatArray(x, 1) = arr(1)
            SeatArray(x, 2) = arr(2)
            SeatArray(x, 3) = arr(3)
            Temp += arr(2)
            x += 1

            For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf ctrl Is Button And ctrl.Text <> "Pay Now" Then
                    'btn = DirectCast(ctrl, Button)
                End If
            Next
        End While
    End Using
```

**Added From Comments**
The four elements on the text file are SeatID, SeatType, SeatPrice, and SeatAvailability.

```
 Sub Gold_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

     SeatInfo.Show() 
     SeatInfo.lblclass.Text = "Gold" 
End Sub
```

The "Gold" refers to a different part of the program that I have already done.

Public Class SeatInfo
    Dim SeatTotal As Decimal = 0
    Dim totalbooking As Integer = 0

```
Public Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnadult.CheckedChanged
    Dim SeatClass As String = lblclass.Text

    Select Case SeatClass
        Case "Gold"
            SeatTotal = 30
        Case Else
            SeatTotal = 0
    End Select
    SeatTotalBox.Text = FormatCurrency(SeatTotal, 2)
End Sub

Public Sub RadioButton5_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtncon.CheckedChanged
    Dim SeatClass As String = lblclass.Text

    Select Case SeatClass
        Case "Gold"
            SeatTotal = 20
        Case Else
            SeatTotal = 0
    End Select
    SeatTotalBox.Text = FormatCurrency(SeatTotal, 2)
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    totalbooking += SeatTotal
    BookingScreen.lbltotalbooking.Text = FormatCurrency(totalbooking, 2)
    Me.Hide()
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf BookingScreen.Reserve_Click
    'If Accept Booking has been pressed, set button to 'red' to signal a reserved seat. 
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please post the code you have that attempted to solve this problem.

Comment: Where are you creating the buttons or is that where you are stuck?

Comment: I manually added the buttons onto the form

Comment: It looks like you have more than one text file - what is the purpose of each text file and how do they relate to the buttons?

Comment: And some sample input would be helpful as well.

Comment: That was an error , I only have 1 txt file which is seatingplan.txt. 
: The text file contains
SeatID   SeatType   SeatPrice
 I want to make it so that when you click on a certain button on the grid, it displays this information from a specific line in the text file.

Comment: You have three values in your text file, but you have 4 elements in the array - are there 3 or 4 fields per line in your file?  How many buttons in the grid?  Is there one button for each line, or on group of buttons for each line?

Comment: Also, can you post the code of your event handlers (like `Gold_Click`), or if you don't have that code yet, what the handler is supposed to do?  The more information you provide, the more likely we can give you an answer.

Comment: My fault, the four elements on the text file are

SeatID  SeatType  SeatPrice   SeatAvailability
                                                                   Sub Gold_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        SeatInfo.Show()
        SeatInfo.lblclass.Text = "Gold"
    End Sub                                                         The "Gold" refers to a different part of the program that I have already done.

Comment: Code doesn't format in comments, so its best to edit your question and add it there (which I just did).  Can you post the code for `SeatInfo.Show()`?  I'm trying to understand how the data in the text file is used in the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer, but should give you some idea of where to go.

For starters, I would create a class to hold the information for each seat, like this:

```
Public Class Seat

    Public Property SeatID As Integer
    Public Property SeatType As String
    Public Property SeatPrice As Decimal
    Public Property SeatAvailability As String
End Class
```

Next, I would use the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class to do the parsing, and build a `List(Of Seat)` list with the data, like this:

```
Dim List(Of Seat) seatList As New List(Of Seat)

Using parser As TextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser("seatingplan.txt")

    parser.Delimiters = New String() { vbTab }

    While Not parser.EndOfData

        Dim fields As String() = parser.ReadFields()

        seatList.Add(New Seat() With { _ 
            .SeatID = Convert.ToInt32(fields(0)), _
            .SeatType = field(1),
            .SeatPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(fields(2)), _
            .SeatAvailability = fields(3) _
        }
    End While
End Using
```

You can now access the information from the individual lines in the file through the List, starting at 0 for the first line, like this:

```
Dim Id As Integer = seatList(0).SeatID
```

I'm not entirely sure how your program is put together and what goes there, but here's an example of using the data based on the button clicked.

Let's say that use a naming convention in for your button's that ends in a number that corresponds to the line of the text file.  For simplicity, `Button_1`, `Button_2`, etc.

```
Public Sub SeatButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    Dim buttonID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(btn.SubString("_" + 1))

    Dim seatInformation = seatList(buttonID - 1)        
End Sub
```

Essentially, `SeatButton_Click` is a handler you could assign to the appropriate buttons.  When it is called, it will get the id number of the button (which corresponds to the line in the file) - basically it grabs everything after the `_` and converts it to an integer.

It then uses that value minus 1 to get the appropriate `Seat` object from the List.  It's button id value - 1 because collections are 0 based (the 0th element is the first line, the 1st element is the 2nd line, etc).

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim. However, I have been using " lbltext.Text = seatList(2).SeatID" to test the code and nothing seems to be displaying. Is there something I have missed out? Should I be using it with the code I already have?

Comment: @user2691281 - try stepping through the code in the debugger to see what is in `seatList`.  The code I posted is somewhat independent of your code, as I'm not entirely clear on how everything in your program is tied together.  The general concept I was trying to illustrate is to build a `List` of seat objects, which could then be accessed by whatever portions of your program need the information.  For this to work `seatList` would need to be class level variable.